# Trigger before delete

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, database-trigger, dml

I created a before delete trigger:

```
create or replace trigger myTrigger3 
before delete on emp
for each row
begin
    update emp set mgr = 'Null' where mgr = :old.emp_name;
end;
```

Where table  is

`emp(emp_id integer primary key, emp_name varchar(20), mgr varchar(20))`

But when I run this statement the trigger is not running.

```
delete from emp where emp_id = 1004;
select * from emp;
```

> Error report -
>      ORA-04091: table DB20178004.EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
>      ORA-06512: at "DB20178004.MYTRIGGER3", line 2
>      ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DB20178004.MYTRIGGER3'

Comment: You cannot manipulate table data while the data of the table is already changing. You would have to update the table **after delete statement**. One way is an after delete trigger without `for each row`, where you update all managers no longer found in the table. Another is to use a compound trigger, where you remember all deleted IDs in the `after each row` section and use them in the `after statement` section for the updates.

Comment: On a side note: `set mgr = 'Null'` should probably be `set mgr = null`. You don't really want to set mgr to a string containing the word 'Null', do you?

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer adding a foreign key constraint with `set null` option instead of such a trigger. Of course you need a primary key should already been defined on `emp_id` column :

```
alter table emp 
add constraint fk_mgr foreign key(mgr)
references emp(emp_id)
on delete set null;
```

Whenever you delete the record with an `emp_id` which has matching values with `mgr` column those will be emptied after deletion of the record with that `emp_id`.

> But please prefer a data type(numeric) for `mgr` conforming with the column
>   `emp_id` such as `integer` to be able to define a foreign key
>   constraint.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=989a8d73dd5a70053b7d25c7c67b4302)</kbd>

By the way,

- I recommend you to use soft-deletion. e.g. adding a column active to the table and
  set value of it to zero whenever want to delete, and do not show the
  records with active=0 on the application.
- If you insisting on deletion do not filter by `emp_name` column, since
  there can be more than one people with the common name, but using `emp_id`
  is better by far as being unique within the table.